# Form within a form/ grid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

please guide me here as am new to rails. I am using rails 5 and bootstrap to create a simple application for managing employees. When entering the information of a new employee, if s/he has a car, a grid appears capturing the model, colour and age of the car. If the employee has no car, then this grid is not launched.

How can I implement such grids/tables which are launched upon selecting a given option? I am also using simple_form gem.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, that sound pretty doable, however you probably should share some code and be more specific, so the community can give you a better answer. Having said that, an idea to achieve what you want is: you can have another model called `Car`, then in your employee form can have a button "I have a car", and that button trigger a boostrap model with the  form for car. In your employee model you can add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :car` and also update your employee controller, `employee_params` should accept nested attr for car.  Share some code and I will be happy to help

Comment: Please share some code of your attempts so far, better direction can be given then!

Comment: Thank you @Horacio for pointing me to the right direction. I am now using cocoon gem to implement the same